# How to rank from highest value in column within group in multi level R data.table

Tags: r, data.table, rank

## My Goal is to create "overall rank" and "rank sec" columns

```
# data
TYPE    CODE    SUM   overall rank  rank sec
old     AB      93       7           2
old     LI      220      6           1
new     EE      500      3           1
new     HH      1.4      11          5
new     AB      23.3     9           3
new     xxx     62.05    8           2
new     LI      10.68    10          4
end     EE      500      3           3
end     HH      384.6    5           4
end     AB      600      2           2
end     xxx     1375.7   1           1
```

## first overall column can be achieved like below

```
data[order(SUM,decreasing = T,),"overall rank":=1:.N][]
```

## This script for the second column doesn't work

```
data[order(SUM,decreasing = T,),"rank sec":=1:.N,by=c("TYPE","CODE")][]
```

## What is the most effective way to achieve the goal with data.table style ?

Comment: The second line of code, have only one row per group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to group by only 'TYPE' as there is only one row per 'TYPE/CODE' combination

```
setDT(data)[order(SUM, decreasing = TRUE), rank_sec := seq_len(.N), .(TYPE)]
data
#    TYPE CODE     SUM overall rank rank_sec
# 1:  old   AB   93.00       7    2        2
# 2:  old   LI  220.00       6    1        1
# 3:  new   EE  500.00       3    1        1
# 4:  new   HH    1.40      11    5        5
# 5:  new   AB   23.30       9    3        3
# 6:  new  xxx   62.05       8    2        2
# 7:  new   LI   10.68      10    4        4
# 8:  end   EE  500.00       3    3        3
# 9:  end   HH  384.60       5    4        4
#10:  end   AB  600.00       2    2        2
#11:  end  xxx 1375.70       1    1        1
```

Comment: apologise , i made a mistake on overall rank column .It should not exist in that table framework .  I was attempted to give the rank base on highest value within every group but forget the structure also should be changed if i want to put the overall rank. Otherwise , i have to made another sum of "CODE" column with rank column , then lookup back to the multi layer dataset with repeating rank value